# <select> event 'change' not firing on 'selectedIndex' change

Tags: jquery, events, html-select

The `change`event is correctly fired when I manually change the `<select>` value clicking on my user interface, but setting the selected index like this...

```
this.selectedIndex = 0;
```

...will not fire the attached event.

Which event should I bind the change to? Is there any workaround besides firing the change event manually? (i.e.: `$(this).change();` after setting the selected index.)

Comment: As the answers below suggest, there isn't a workaround that doesn't involve manually triggering the change event handler.

Comment: first off, it would be more consistent if you used .on('change, function()..')

Comment: @AnthonyGrist what a pity. I thought maybe there was a way to bind to property changes.

Comment: @BenSewards I didn't post the binding code, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try triggering it by code:

```
$(this).trigger('change');
```

Comment: `$(this).change()` is just a shorthand for `$(this).trigger('change')`. I'm already aware of this solution.

Comment: @kaoD Yes, but its still what youre asking for, and afaik, there is no other way

Comment: So your answer doesn't answer my question, right? *"AFAIK, there's no way to do that"* would probably be a better answer, but *"AFAIK"* doesn't belong to a answer so... Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @kaoD I just answered "Is there any workaround besides firing the change event manually?". Unless you want to run the same code that you run in the change event after you change the index manually, that is.

Comment: Did you miss *"besides firing the change event manually"*? I'm grateful that you took some time to answer, but it does **NOT** answer my question.

Comment: @kaoD If you want to use jquery, you have the two options that i mentioned. Trigger it manually or run the same code after you change the index manually. There is no other way. Period.

Answer (score 1):

After setting the `.selectedIndex`, do the following to trigger the onchange event:

```
$('#yourselect').trigger('change');
```