# How to add addEventListener to custom select Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to add on "change" listener to the custom select menu created exactly according to the https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp  but no event is triggered when I select an option.

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item: */
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);

/* This part is not working */
var select = document.querySelector("#cars");
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
      console.log(this.value)
});
```

```css
/* The container must be positioned relative: */

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
  /*hide original SELECT element: */
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}


/* Style the arrow inside the select element: */

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}


/* style the items (options), including the selected item: */

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Style items (options): */

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}


/* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="cars">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When I want to get the selected option value with on "change" listener, after I change the option, nothing happens.

```
var select = document.querySelector("#cars");
select.addEventListener("change",function(){
    console.log(this.value)
}
```

Comment: Looks like your trouble is coming from somewhere else.  When I eliminate all of the other javascript the `console.log(this.value);` works without any issues. 
 https://jsfiddle.net/8roc2p6n/  I tried this first because that piece looks correct to me, and it is.

Comment: i don't understand why you use so much `js` to override select and show.

Comment: It’s sad how much examples on that site are unusable for people with disabilities, and that there is no mention whatsoever. So @madmax80, please be aware that replacing native controls by custom ones comes with a lot of caveats, especially in terms of accessibility. Keyboard navigation, selecting options by typing their first letters, and usability with screen readers are all lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that simply setting the original (now hidden) `<select>` by updating its selectedIndex value does not trigger the window event required for the event listener to fire.  You can test this in console even with the changes made below by setting the selected index repeatedly for the original `<select>` and it will not fire the event:

`document.getElementById("cars").selectedIndex = 2;`

To get around this, in your click function that you bind in the original series of loops you can manually trigger the event to fire like this.

`s.dispatchEvent(new window.Event("change"));`

Look for the comment:

`// ================== NEW LINE TO FIRE EVENT MANUALLY =======================`

Solution below:

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item: */
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          // ================== NEW LINE TO FIRE EVENT MANUALLY =======================
          s.dispatchEvent(new window.Event("change"));
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);

var select = document.querySelector("#cars");
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value)
});
```

```css
/* The container must be positioned relative: */

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
  /*hide original SELECT element: */
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}


/* Style the arrow inside the select element: */

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}


/* style the items (options), including the selected item: */

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Style items (options): */

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}


/* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="cars">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Lucretius, this is a perfectly valid answer to my problem. I was not sure why that custom select box from W3school doesn't trigger an event for any listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="cars" onchange="myfunction();">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

//try this

```
 <script>
function myfunction(){
console.log('value changed');
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code is changing the `selectedIndex` of the native `<select>`, but [this does not fire the `change` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726297/select-event-change-not-firing-on-selectedindex-change)!

So you will need to do it yourself:

```js
…
if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          const changeEvent = new InputEvent('change');
          s.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

See [Creating and triggering built-in events on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#triggering_built-in_events)

**Warning of custom controls**

Please be also aware that while custom controls might look nice, they pose a whole bunch of issues, most notably they pose usability issues for users with disabilities. First and foremost, keyboard controls (Arrow Up/Down, Home, End, Page Up/Down, Type to search) need to be implemented manually, which also is expected from power users. See the [Combobox pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/) to get an idea of how complex a seemingly simple `<select>` actually is.

Here is the full code of your example for demonstration:

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item: */
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          // inform anybody listening about the change
          const changeEvent = new InputEvent('change');
          s.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);

/* This part is not working */
var select = document.querySelector("#cars");
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
      console.log(this.value)
});
```

```css
/* The container must be positioned relative: */

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
  /*hide original SELECT element: */
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}


/* Style the arrow inside the select element: */

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}


/* style the items (options), including the selected item: */

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Style items (options): */

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}


/* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="cars">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
  </select>
</div>
```